# Product measurability of function within the integral

Tags: measure-theory

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}\newcommand{\B}{\mathcal{B}{(\mathbb{R})}}\newcommand{\Bt}{\mathcal{B}({\R^2})}$
Let $f : \R^2 \to \R_{\geq 0}, (x, y) \mapsto f(x, y)$ be measurable in $x$, i.e. for fixed $y \in \R$, $\{x \mid f(x, y) \in B\} \in \B$. Let $g : \B \times \R \to \R_{\geq 0}, (A, y) \mapsto g(A, y)$ be measurable in $y$. Further, let $f$ and $g$ be related as follows:

$\displaystyle\int_A f(x, y) \mathrm{\ d}x = g(A, y)$

that is, for each $y$, $g$ is a measure in $A$, absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure, with $f$ being the Radon-Nikodym derivative (for fixed $y$).

**Question:** Do these conditions also imply that $f$ is product-(joint-) measurable in $x, y$ ?

**Motivation:** This appears as follows. Consider the conditional probability measure generated by $\mathbb{E}[{\mathbf{1}(X \in A) \mid Y}] = g(A, Y)$. Then $g$ is measurable in $Y$ for fixed $A$, and a measure in $A$. In this question, $g$ is generated by the kernel $f$.